# How to have restriction in subfolders when logged in

Tags: authentication, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish

Before i start , i've checked a lot of tutorials , and a lot of questions in stackoverflow, but none of them seemed to give me what i wanted, here is my problem:

i have a class:User , and 3 others that extends from user : admin, recruteur and candidat

what i did (and what i've found in all the tutorials and questiosn here) is to put a filter when the user logs in, so if he is logged in he can view the folder secured/* but if not , he will be redirected to login.xhtml

now what i want , is to add the other folders , so an admin can only access admin folder+secured folder , recruter can only access secured+recruter folder ect...

for now i've put adminFolder,recruterFolder,candidatFolder in securedFolder,but i couldn't manage to make the restrictions to the subfolders . Here is the code of my filter

```
//user=member
 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  
     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {     
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
     HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

     String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml";

     boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("membre") != null;
     boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);
     boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

     if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
     } else {
         response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
     }

     }
```

Comment: What's the program currently printing out?

Comment: i removed the print, it was printing the user role for future uses 
i was calling a function to get the dtype(dtype=user role)

Comment: But I guess you need to get the role attribute here in order to limit user access.

Comment: yes yes, i know , that's what i'm looking , for , how ? 
i can get the role user, but i don't know the code that i need to add to only let him enter secured and its folder only , not all other folders

Comment: Something like `if (request.getRequestURI().contains("adminFolder")) response.sendRedirect(loginURI);`?

Comment: exactly ! i just need it implemented in my code 
where should i put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another filter (same filter as yours , except added the

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;  

public class SecuredRoleFilter implements Filter{


 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  
     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {     
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
     HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

     String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml";

     boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("role").equals("Candidat");
     boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);
     boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

     if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
     } else {
         response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
     }

     }  

 @Override
     public void destroy() {}

 @Override
 public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }  

}
```

now in web.xml add the filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>secured</filter-name>
    <filter-class>packageName.ConxFilter</filter-class>       
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>secured</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>       
</filter-mapping>

<filter>  
    <filter-name>securedCandidat</filter-name>
    <filter-class>packageName.SecuredRoleFilter</filter-class>        
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>securedCandidat</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secured/candidatFolder/*</url-pattern>        
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: actually , i think this is the best way to dot it

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your filter:

```
if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
    Membre membre = (Membre)session.getAttribute("membre");
    if (request.getRequestURI().contains("adminFolder") 
        && !"ADMIN".equals(membre.getDtype())){

        //When user tries to access the admin folder without being ADMIN, 
        //redirect to login page
        response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
    } else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
} else {
    response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
}
```

Comment: what about the solution given before this post? 
creating a new filter for each user ? and add it to web.xml ?
i tried it and it works

Comment: It is other way to do it. It really depends on how you want to have your code organized. All in all, I would go with an abstract `SecuredRoleFilter` in order to avoid having the code duplicated in each of the filters if you go that way. For my solution you should check different roles into the `if` statement.

Comment: yes, adding a superclass is better to not have duplicate code!
i just wanted to make a simple solution